# Critical error in a database. Missing wp_actionscheduler_actions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Need some help with wordpress (woocoommerce error)

It seem the wp_action scheduler_actions is gone. Need to generated it again. and no back up =S

2024-02-27T01:37:48+00:00 Critical Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to claim actions. Database error: Table 'wordpress.wp_actionscheduler_actions' doesn't exist. in /volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/action-scheduler/classes/data-stores/ActionScheduler_DBStore.php:942
Additional context
2024-02-27T01:41:51+00:00 Critical Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to claim actions. Database error: Table 'wordpress.wp_actionscheduler_actions' doesn't exist. in /volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/action-scheduler/classes/data-stores/ActionScheduler_DBStore.php:942
Additional context
2024-02-27T01:42:53+00:00 Critical Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to claim actions. Database error: Table 'wordpress.wp_actionscheduler_actions' doesn't exist. in /volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/action-scheduler/classes/data-stores/ActionScheduler_DBStore.php:942
Additional context
2024-02-27T01:44:18+00:00 Critical Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to claim actions. Database error: Table 'wordpress.wp_actionscheduler_actions' doesn't exist. in /volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/action-scheduler/classes/data-stores/ActionScheduler_DBStore.php:942
Additional context
2024-02-27T01:46:51+00:00 Critical Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to claim actions. Database error: Table 'wordpress.wp_actionscheduler_actions' doesn't exist. in /volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/action-scheduler/classes/data-stores/ActionScheduler_DBStore.php:942
Additional context
2024-02-27T01:49:08+00:00 Critical Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to claim actions. Database error: Table 'wordpress.wp_actionscheduler_actions' doesn't exist. in /volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/action-scheduler/classes/data-stores/ActionScheduler_DBStore.php:942

Hope someone have the same database and have the instruction that i could fix it in phpmyadmin.

Comment: define ('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true); in your config file  then run this address mydomain/wp-admin/main/repair.php . Create backup of your database before that. https://wp-kama.com/handbook/codex/wp-config-php#wp_allow_repair

Comment: I did try it before but database cannot recover 

    Failed to repair the wp_actionscheduler_actions table. Error: Table 'wordpress.wp_actionscheduler_actions' doesn't exist